# Running Custom Shell Command from Python Script inside Docker Container

Tags: python, bash, docker

I am trying to run a custom shell command from a python script inside a docker container and capture the output for later use. My code is:

```
def live_who_is(domain):
        live_data = subprocess.check_output('whois {}'.format(domain), shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        print(live_data)
```

and I get this error when I run it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "who_is_compare_script.py", line 158, in <module>
    live_who_is('google.com')
  File "who_is_compare_script.py", line 149, in live_who_is
    live_data = subprocess.check_output('whois {}'.format(domain), shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 223, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command 'whois google.com' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

If you replace the command with "ls -a" or even "ls {}".format("-a") it works.

Comment: Have you tried running `whois google.com` from your shell and checking the output/exit code?

Comment: `whois` is not a shell command, it's a program. Further, can you do this without docker? If not, you could reduce your problem/question.

Comment: I have tried running it from my shell and it works. Unfortunately is has to be run inside the docker container

Answer (score 0):

I changed the line to subprocess.call('whois {}'.format(domain), shell=True) and it worked

Comment: Can you retrieve the registrar information for `google.com; rm -rf /`?

Comment: DO NOT EXECUTE THIS COMMAND! @DavidMaze is trying to **trick you into deleting your whole system**. **Do. Not. Execute. This. Command**.

Comment: The more specific point is that `subprocess.call(..., shell=True)` is a major lurking security issue.